# Need help in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have a file with below content. I would like to read line by line and if the 2nd part of any line is more than 180, I need to send out an email to the group. Please suggest me on how to implement it in a shell script.

```
./NODE0000 83
./NODE0001 82
./NODE0002 81
./NODE0003 81
./NODE0004 236
./NODE0005 81
./NODE0006 82
./NODE0007 81
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the command you need to use to send the email?

Comment: 1. Figure out how to read line-by-line. 2. Figure out how to get the second field. 3. Figure out how to do something based on that value. 4. Figure out how to send an email.

Comment: Doesnt look like you have even tried to write the shell script yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try a script like below, use it like: `./readLineAndEmail.sh filename.txt`

```
 #!/bin/bash
 while read line
 do
   digit=$(echo $line | awk ' { print $2 } ')
    if [ "$digit" -ge 180 ]
      then

         email-script-and-other-stuff

      fi
  done < $1
```

Comment: Thank you MiinimalLogic, 
It reads the entire file and checks if it is greater than 180. I am looking for some thing like to read line by line and if any particular line is greater than 180, then send out an email.
In my above example, NODE0004 matches the criteria. So it should send the email showing that NODE0004 is more than 180.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$2>180' file | mail -s alert you@domain.tld,another@domain.tld
```